# Oracle bind vars does not work with ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, oracle, activerecord

I have a problem with Oracle 'bind variables' and ActiveRecord. 
How AR can use 'bind variables'?

I am trying to use oracle and oracle-enhanced adapters, set cursor_sharing directives to 'force' or 'similar', but result SQL query does not contain bind vars, only plain string.
I am using AR 2.0.2 and 3.1+.

And maybe console verbose does not show full SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With cursor_sharing = FORCE,  it is unlikely that bind variables are not being used, but RoR will not know anything about them. Active Record will still send the queries to the database without binds, and then Oracle will force bind variables into the place of all literals. Therefore in the Rails console, you will just see the original SQL with no binds.

To confirm your SQL statements are using binds, query v$sql with something like:

```
select sql_fulltext 
from v$sql
where upper(sql_fulltext) like '%TABLE IN YOUR APP%'
```

You should see your original queries in the output, but with bind variables in place of the values you had passed in.